# How can I remove a specific amount of items from a player with commands, only when the player has equal or more than the requiered items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to do it, with specific quantity of items, such as 2 ender eyes, for example:

```
/execute if data entity @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:eye_of_ender",Count:2b}]}
```

But it doesn't work if the player has more than 2, what can I do?

Comment: @pppery In a way, yes, but with that command, for example it would remove 3 iron ingots, even if the player has less. I want to remove certain quantity only if the player has enough of it. For instance, remove a stack of rotten flesh only if the player has a stack, no less

Comment: @pppery Yes, but then again, I tried that command and it worked, it didnt work if the player had less than the Count part, but my problem is that it doesnt work if it the player has more of said item neither, idk if it is a problem in my side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect whether a player has two of a specific item in their inventory, and drop one?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378718/how-to-detect-whether-a-player-has-two-of-a-specific-item-in-their-inventory-an)

Answer (score 3):

Setup:

`scoreboard objectives add eyesOfEnder dummy`

Run these commands every tick:

`execute store result score #count eyesOfEnder run clear @p minecraft:eye_of_ender 0`

`execute if score #count eyesOfEnder matches 2.. run clear @p minecraft:eye_of_ender 2`

Comment: My objective is to make a shop. I have a mod installed that adds coins, and I want to use those coins instead of the scoreboard setup. Ex: 2 coins for 2 ender pearls. That would be `clear @p[{Inventory:[{id:"mod:coin",Count:2}]}] mod:coins 2` and then `give @p enderpearl 2`

Comment: @pontorka so this doesn't work? Why not? I'm a bit confused as to why you can't just change ender pearls to coins?

Answer (score -1):

do /clear (playername) and then the item example: Minecraft:stone 5.
if you type that you remove 5 stone out of his inventory

Comment: But then if I have 3 it will take them.